# SQL Server, How to pull all references to tables and columns used in stored procedures from other databases

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to get a list of all tables and columns being referenced within every stored procedure within a certain database (`DatabaseA`).

I have the following script written that accomplishes this just fine from what it appears first glance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    O.name SP_Name, T.name Table_Name, c.name Field_Name
FROM 
    sys.sysdepends D 
JOIN 
    sys.sysobjects O ON O.id = D.id
JOIN 
    sys.sysobjects T ON T.id = D.depid
JOIN 
    sys.columns C ON C.column_id = d.depnumber
                  AND C.object_id = D.depID
WHERE 
    O.xtype = 'P'
```

So this appears to pull in all table and column references for `DatabaseA`'s stored procedures, but only for `DatabaseA`'s tables.

How can I get it to reference all other databases that may be called within these stored procedures? All the other databases reside on the same server.

Comment: sysobjects etc. have been deprecated since SQL Server 2005. Look at sys.objects and sys.sql_expression_dependencies. Some examples of answers I've written in the past that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sys.sql_expression_dependencies+user%3A61305

Comment: Avoid using the deprecated backwards compatibility views (sysdepends, sysobjects).  Use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` and `sys.objects`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`:

```
select 
    ProcedureSchema = schema_name(o.schema_id),
    ProcedureName = o.name,
    ReferencedSchema = schema_name(t.schema_id),
    ReferencedName = t.name,
    ReferencedType = t.Type_desc
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies xd
inner join sys.objects o
    on xd.Referencing_id = o.object_id
        and o.type = 'P'
inner join sys.objects t
    on xd.referenced_id = t.object_id
```

You could also use `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` which is a table-valued function which takes in an object. It gives you some additional information (such as how various columns are used).

```
select top 1000 *
from sys.objects o
cross apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(schema_name(o.schema_id) + '.' + o.name, 'OBJECT') r
where o.type = 'P'
```

Be aware however, if you want to target cross database references, using object_ids to join to, say, `sys.objects` as I've shown above *will not work*. Since an `object_id` in one database does not equate to the same object in another database. In that case, you'll need to use the columns surfaced by either the dmv or function e.g. `referenced_database_name`, `referenced_schema_name`, `referenced_entity_name`, `referenced_minor_name`.

Also, if any of those references are not properly qualified (e.g. if someone wrote `inner join OtherDatabase..SomeTable` you'll run into problems because it won't actually parse the missing name part.)

So in short, these approaches have a few caveats, but are about as good as you're going to get.